# Prove that if $x\geq 1$ and $p\in\mathbb{Q}$, then $x^p=\sup\{x^q\mid q\in\mathbb{Q},q<p\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, exponentiation

This is what I have so far (I don't know if this is the best approach):

Since $x\geq 1$, we know that for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q<p$, we have $x^q\leq x^p$.

Taking supremums on $q$, we get $\sup\{x^q\mid q\in\mathbb{Q},q<p\}\leq x^p$.

By contradiction, suppose that there exists $\varepsilon>0$ such that $x^q+\varepsilon\leq x^p$ for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q<p$. Let's write $p:=\dfrac{m_1}{n}$ and $q:=\dfrac{m_2}{n}$. Then, $(x^q+\varepsilon)^n\leq x^{m_1}$. Therefore, $\left(1+\dfrac{\varepsilon}{x^q}\right)^n\leq\dfrac{x^{m_1}}{x^{m_2}}$.

Using Bernouilli's inequality, we've got $1+n\cdot\dfrac{\varepsilon}{x^q}\leq\dfrac{x^{m_1}}{x^{m_2}}$.

I can't reach any contradiction from here.

---

Has someone any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This very much depends on what results you are allowed to use. At least you need a definition of $x^p$ - which is not obvious at all. E.g. the definition could be $\exp(p\log x)$.

Comment: Take $n\in \mathbb Z$ large enough such that $1+n\frac{\epsilon}{x^p}>x$ and that $pn$ is an integer (why can you do that?), and take $q=\frac{pn-1}{n}<p$, now plug that into the final inequality you had there.

Comment: "Since $x\geq 1$, we know that for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $q<p$, we have $x^q\leq x^p$." I think this is one of the things you need to *prove*.